# Why is the return type of the fold operation Serializable and not String

Tags: scala

Here is a simple scala code

```
scala> val x = scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[String, String]("a"->"a", "b"->"b")
x: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[String,String] = Map(a -> a, b -> b)
scala> val y = x.fold(""){case (acc: String, (k: String, v: String)) => acc + s""", "$k":"$v""""}
y: java.io.Serializable = , "a":"a", "b":"b"
```

Why is the return type of `y` not String but java.io.Serializable?

I thought it could be because I am using pattern matching and the match can be non-exhaustive. So I changed my code to

```
scala> val y = x.fold(""){case (acc: String, (k:String, v:String)) => acc + s""", "$k":"$v"""" case _ => ""}
y: java.io.Serializable = , "a":"a", "b":"b"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of `fold` is:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

Both operands of the the folding operation (`op`) must be of the same type, but in your case they are `String` and `(String, String)`, so the compiler instead tries to look for the least-upper bound between the two types, and finds `Serializable`.

`foldLeft` and `foldRight` allow the accumulator and next element to be different types, so those can work.

```
scala> x.foldLeft("") { case (acc, (k, v)) => acc + s""", "$k":"$v"""" }
res8: String = , "a":"a", "b":"b"
```

Folding isn't really what you want here, though, because you'll end up with that extra comma unless you handle it specially. Instead, you could use `map` and `mkString`.

```
scala> x.map { case (k, v) =>  s""""$k":"$v"""" }.mkString(", ")
res10: String = "a":"a", "b":"b"
```

I also removed the type ascriptions, as they were not necessary.